# How does one 'read' a file from a Dart VM program?

Tags: dart

How does one 'read' a file from a Dart program ?

http://api.dartlang.org/index.html

Dart would be running on the client-side and so taking files as input should be allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find a usage of files in Dart's testing framework:
[status_file_parser.dart](http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/tools/testing/dart/status_file_parser.dart?spec=svn3418&r=2996) (search for 'File').

In short:

```
  File file = new File(path);
  if (!file.existsSync()) <handle missing file>;
  InputStream file_stream = file.openInputStream();
  StringInputStream lines = new StringInputStream(file_stream);

  lines.lineHandler = () {
    String line;
    while ((line = lines.readLine()) != null) {
    ...
  };
  lines.closeHandler = () {
    ...
  };
```

Note that the API is not yet finalized and could change at any moment.

Edit: API has changed. See [Introduction to new IO](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/io/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies you want to do this from the client-side, that is, the browser. The `dart:io` library only works in the stand-alone VM on the command line.

If you do want to read a file from within the VM, there's now an easier way:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  var filename = new Options().script;
  var file = new File(filename);

  if (!file.existsSync()) {
    print("File $filename does not exist");
    return;
  }

  var contents = file.readAsStringSync();

  print(contents);
}
```

If you do not want to block while the whole file is read, you can use the async version of `readAsString` which returns a Future:

```
  file.readAsString().then((contents) {
    print(contents);
  });
```